# How to forward a call to SIP server

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I have a SIP server(Asterisk) I have configured a DID for outbound and inbound. My asterisk server has freepbx installed to manage it. My requirement here is, when anyone calls to this DID call should be forwarded to other SIP server(Nextone SBC). Forwarding is not working.

I have created the trunk on Asterisk for for Nextone.

Comment: Did you configure routes as well?